# ConsumerGroup consumerOptions Configuration error @types/kafka-node

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, node-kafka

I'm trying to use consumerGroup instead of HighLevelConsumer in a typescript project, but I'm not able to configure consumerOptions for consumerGroup.

I am getting the following error when I assign

1) fromOffset: 'earliest'

> Argument of type '{ autoCommit: boolean; fetchMaxBytes: number;
>   fetchMaxWaitMs: number; fromOffset: string; groupId...' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'ConsumerGroupOptions'. Types of
>   property 'fromOffset' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not
>   assignable to type '"earliest" | "latest" | "none"'.

2) protocol: ['roundrobin']

> Argument of type '{ autoCommit: boolean; fetchMaxBytes: number;
>   fetchMaxWaitMs: number; protocol: string[]; groupId...' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'ConsumerGroupOptions'. Types of
>   property 'protocol' are incompatible. Type 'string[]' is not
>   assignable to type '("roundrobin" | "range" |
>   CustomPartitionAssignmentProtocol)[]'. Type 'string' is not assignable
>   to type '"roundrobin" | "range" | CustomPartitionAssignmentProtocol'.

3) outOfRangeOffset: 'earliest'

> Argument of type '{ autoCommit: boolean; fetchMaxBytes: number;
>   fetchMaxWaitMs: number; outOfRangeOffset: string; g...' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'ConsumerGroupOptions'. Types of
>   property 'outOfRangeOffset' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not
>   assignable to type '"earliest" | "latest" | "none"'.

Environment details:

- Node version: v8.11.1
- Kafka-node version: v2.6.1
- types/kafka-node: v2.0.6

Can anyone help me understand where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the code?